# AngularJS - ngSwitch and ngClick not working in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I want to display the elements of a list thanks to a `ngSwitch` but I can't figure out how to do with a `ngRepeat`. I've begun by doing it without a list, just to understand how `ngSwitch` works and to show you what I want to do, here's a jsFiddle that will help you understand: [jdFiffle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Sylla/5P64B/)

Then, I try to use a list with `ngRepeat` but, whatever I try to do, it doesn't work. Here's a second jsFiddle with, this time, the use of a list: [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Sylla/gAzEk/)

It seems that `ngClick` and `ngSwitch` don't work when they're inside a `ngRepeat`... How can I do to make things work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some problems:

1. When dealing with angular-directives, you usually don't need to use the `{{...}}` syntax, just use the *real* values. So instead of:

   ```
   data-ng-click="sw='{{test.name}}'"
   ```

   use:

   ```
   data-ng-click="sw = test.name"
   ```

   *(see next point for why this won't be enough)*
2. `ng-repeat` uses its own scope with transclusion, so the above will set `sw` in the wrong scope, use:

   ```
   data-ng-click="$parent.sw = test.name"
   ```
3. you can't build `ng-switch-when`'s with `ng-repeat`, try `ng-show/hide` instead try:

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="test in tests" ng-show="sw == test.name">
   ```

demo: http://jsbin.com/uxobot/1/

---

But all in all, I don't see the need for `ng-switch/ng-repeat` on the second div. The following has the same effect and is probably a lot more semantic:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="click">
    <div ng-repeat="test in tests" data-ng-click="$parent.active = test">
      {{test.name}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="switch">
    {{active.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/elufow/1/